# Duplicate definition of column 'username' on entity FOSUserBundle FOSRestBundle JMSSerializerBundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle

I am trying to use FOSUserBundle with FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializer.

I have successfully got the RESTFul modules working so i am able to access /api/v1/users/ however it returns all DB fields from FOSUserBundle and i want to be able to specify which ones to provide.

I have got this working on my other modules by adding @Expose to my annotation in the respective modules Entity. However there is no entity for the FOSUserBundle that i can see and when trying to create my own (provided below) it throws up this exception:

> MappingException: Duplicate definition of column 'username' on entity 'CYLO\UserBundle\Entity\User' in a field or discriminator column mapping.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide serialization definition for the class FOS\UserBundle\Model\User. For example, using YAML file named Model.User.yml:

```
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
        username:
            expose: true
        email:
            expose: true
```

Then configure jms serializer like this:

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: false
        directories:
            FOSUserBundle:
                namespace_prefix: FOS\UserBundle
                path: "@MyOwnBundle/Resources/config/serializer"
                ...
```

Comment: Thanks, i knew it would be something trivial.